# Google Webmaster Tools links to my site disappeared

Tags: google-search-console, backlinks

Last week I had over 900 links to my site from 113 domains. At the start of the week Webmaster showed this fall to 30 links and then today 21 links from 11 domains.

I know that Webmaster Tools are incorrect here - in Google Analytics I can see hundreds of referrers and I can Google search for my websites name and find many many links.

I ahve all 4 versions of my site on Webmaster Tools `www.example.com`, `example.com`, `https://example.com` and `https://www.example.com`. When someone visits the site redirects all point to `https://example.com`.

I'm aware that this was a bug previously on Webmaster Tools. Is anyone else experiencing this and what should I do?

Comment: Have you checked to see how many of those 900 still exist? I suspect you've dropped a few site wide links. Blogrolls have a habit of doing that. let me know.

Comment: Since this is about a bug that will be fixed soon, closing as "too localized" because it is about an event that will not be relevant long.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller OK but it seems that, from looking at the links provided in the answer, this bug on Google Webmaster happens often. Might be worth leaving up for any future bugs on Googles part

Comment: Closed does not mean that this question will be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google changed something on their end such that webmaster tools is not reporting as many backlinks. There are several people reporting this phenomenon in [this thread on webmaster world](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4583169.htm)

Edit: [Google is now reporting that this is a bug](http://searchengineland.com/google-webmaster-tools-links-to-your-site-reporting-bug-163753):

> Some Webmaster Tools users have reported missing data in the “Links to your site” section. We are aware of this issue and are looking into it; you do not need to take any action. We hope to have the normal data shown again in the near future. The data shown there is informational and does not affect your site’s crawling, indexing or ranking.